# Defining a python dictionary of lambdas through a for cycle

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to define a dictionary of python lambda functions through a for cycle. Each lambda function needs the value of the relative dictionary key to work, but my hope is to avoid to pass such key as an argument. 
Here is a dummy version of my problem.

Given

```
a = {'bar': 0, 'foo': 1}  # a reference dictionary 

dic1 = {'bar': lambda x: x['bar'], 'foo': lambda x: x['foo']}
dic2 = {key: lambda x: x[key] for key in a}
```

I expect dic1 and dic2 to do the same thing, however only dic1 behaves as I would want to. 
In particular, the result of

```
print(dic1['bar'](a), dic1['foo'](a))
print(dic2['bar'](a), dic2['foo'](a))
```

is

```
0 1
1 1
```

instead of

```
0 1
0 1
```

Comment: This is an interesting problem with a beautiful solution by @jdehesa, but still I must ask what's possibly the use for that? I mean, is a big workaround for simply doing...... `a['bar']`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I agree that this dummy version of the problem might seem useless. In my case the lambda function should act in a non-trivial way based on the their key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work has to do with [late-binding closures](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) in Python.

> Python’s closures are late binding. This means that the values of variables used in closures are looked up at the time the inner function is called.

Adapting the source explanation, whenever the return function is called, the value of `key` is looked up in the surrounding scope at call time. By then, the loop has completed and `key` is left with its final value of `'foo'`.

You can resolve this by creating a closure that binds immediately to its arguments by using a default arg like so:

```py
a = {'bar': 0, 'foo': 1}  # a reference dictionary 

dic1 = {'bar': lambda x: x['bar'], 'foo': lambda x: x['foo']}
dic2 = {key: lambda x, key=key: x[key] for key in a}

print(dic1['bar'](a), dic1['foo'](a))
print(dic2['bar'](a), dic2['foo'](a))
```

Result:

```py
0 1
0 1
```

Comment: It is better practice to explain what the link you are pointing to is describing rather than just linking it.

Comment: final value of 'foo'? Thanks for the details! +1

Answer (score 4):

One simple way to do that is with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = {'bar': 0, 'foo': 1}
dic1 = {key: itemgetter(key) for key in a}
print(dic1['bar'](a), dic1['foo'](a))
# 0 1
```

Alternatively, you need to bind each value of `key` to each dictionary value, typically you do that with something like this:

```
a = {'bar': 0, 'foo': 1}
dic1 = {key: (lambda key: lambda x: x[key])(key) for key in a}
print(dic1['bar'](a), dic1['foo'](a))
# 0 1
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer being correct but do you know why the above doesn't work?

Comment: See my answer for explanation

Comment: @Akaisteph7 In your code, all the lambdas are associated to the comprehension variable `key`, not to the value of the variable on each iteration, so they all end up using the same final value that the variable gets. I added a common way in which that can be avoided, which is passing the variable as an argument to an external lambda in turn.

Comment: @jdehesa It's not my question but thanks for adding some explanation